# Doctrine INDEX BY foreign key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am trying to get summary data for articles from article_stats table indexed with article ids.

The query builder looks like this:

```
$qb = $this->articlesStatsRepository->createQueryBuilder('ass');
$qb->select('SUM(ass.pageviews)')
    ->indexBy('ass', 'ass.article') // this doesnt work
    ->groupBy('ass.article');

$articleStats = $query->getResult();
```

This results in query

```
SELECT SUM(ass.pageviews) 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\ArticleStats ass 
INDEX BY ass.article 
GROUP BY ass.article
```

With an error of:

```
[Semantical Error] near 'article GROUP': 
Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

I've tried `->indexBy('ass', 'IDENTITY(ass.article)')` but that didn't work either.

So how can I select data from database indexed by foreign key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the exact composition of the entities and their relationships, it's hard to give a precise answer.  Even so, if `ass.article` is an entity, and not the numeric article ID, the query will not work.  `INDEX BY` must be used with an ORM column.

An example is included below:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(c.visits) AS visits
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN c.account a
INDEX BY a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

`$results` will contain an associative array of entities indexed by name.  To do this with a foreign key, you may have to do a join first, or use nested DQL.  It is also possible that `INDEX BY` will not work in the exact way that you want.  A workaround would look like this (includes ID as part of associative array instead of as array key):

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(c.visits) AS visits
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN c.account a
GROUP BY a.id
```

If you still cannot get this working after reading over this answer, I'd advise providing additional information about the entities and any relevant relationships.

Comment: This cannot work, indexBy needs a root alias : `a` is not a root alias here.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('SUM(ass.pageviews)')
   ->from('YourBundle:article_stats', 'ass', 'ass.article')
   ->groupBy('ass.article');

$articleStats = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: This produces exactly the same result as the original attempt